# PDO IF page_header = image show code

Tags: php, pdo

What im trying to do is that if in a field in my table [connection Already included, by a config file. YES this works] that if a field is a certain word it will show a piece of code.

```
<?php
$q = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name='page_header'");
 $q -> execute(array($_POST['page_header']));

  if ($page_header == 'image') {
            echo "<center><img src='http://www.freefever.com/stock/animal-abstract-art-wallpaper-hd.jpg' class='img_round' height='500px' width='500px'></center>";
        }

        ?>
```

Edit:

```
<?php
  $q = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name=:page_header");
  $q -> execute(array(':page_header' => $_POST['page_header']));

    $data_array = $q->fetch();
    if ($data_array[0] == 'image') { // what ever your index contains image field
        echo "<center><img src='http://www.freefever.com/stock/animal-abstract-art-wallpaper-hd.jpg' class='img_round' height='500px' width='500px'></center>";
    }



   ?>
```

Comment: So, display the image if the record exists?

Comment: You should take a look at placeholders in prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). page_header should be :page_header or ?.  $q->fetchAll() holds the results. Simply iterate other the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
$data = $q->fetchAll();
```

`$data` now contains an array of associative arrays with the values from the database.

```
$data[0]["page_header"];
```

would be the page_header from the first result row.

UPDATE: And if you want to use prepared statements your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name= :page_header
```

with your array: `array("page_header" => $_POST['page_header'])`

For further information please check the excellent manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Without more code of what you just tried there is no way i can help you. Please update your question with the updated code and / or error messages

Comment: Should I be putting '$data[0]["page_header"];' anywhere? and if so, where?

Comment: Sorry. but you should really try to read the manual i linked you. Your query will select multiple result rows. so with $data[0] you are accessing the array of the first row. And $data[0]["page_header"] is the value of the column "page_header" from the first row.

Comment: Yeah, I took a little read of the prepare manual. But I placed the codes you wrote (except $data[0]["page_header"]) and recieved the same result..

Comment: Could you update your question with what your table looks like and how your code looks now? I am not quite sure what you want to do, so please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: What is the name of the column in your database you want to compare to "image"?

Comment: I dont want to compare. But what I want is a code that checks if the value of the column 'extra' in my table 'pages_extra' and if it has 'images' the code will show an image.

Comment: Then do this: if ($data_array['extra'] === "image"). This checks if your column "extra" is equal to the string "image".

Comment: can please update your answer with what var_dump($data_array); gives you?

Comment: Hi, where abouts should I put it? If i put it up top I get 'Null', if I put it under '$data_array = $q->fetch();' I get bool(false)

Comment: Under $data_array = $q->fetch(); is correct and "bool(false)" indicates that something went wrong with your query. Can you validate that your query works? In phpMyAdmin for example.

Comment: Recieved this error by running it in Phpmyadmin: " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':page_header' at line 1"

Comment: you obviously need to change :page_header to a valid value (e.g what $_POST["page_header"] would contain)

Comment: Just ran 'SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name= page_header' in phpmyadmin, and got '#1054 - Unknown column 'page_header' in 'where clause'' I doubled confirmed that it was the table, name but still. I also went to export the table and it said 'INSERT INTO `pages_extra` (`name`, `extra`, `extra2`, `enabled`, `order`) VALUES
('usersystem', 'dfd', 'ffds', '1', 'N/A');' Meaning why isnt mine working???

Comment: Sorry but i cannot explain you the basics for php and mysql. You should really consider reading a few good tutorials on this matter.

Comment: I know the basic php, mysql. But I have no idea why it wont work, when there is clearly a field there..

Comment: Dont worry, I have managed to fix this issue. Thankyou for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following your code correctly, I think you're missing the ":" before page_header in the prepare statement.

Comment: Yeah I end up putting :page_header, still same result

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the task

```
  <?php
  $q = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name=:page_header");
  $q -> execute(array(':page_header' => $_POST['page_header']));

    $data_array = $q->fetch();
    if ($data_array[0] == 'image') { // what ever your index contains image field
        echo "<center><img src='http://www.freefever.com/stock/animal-abstract-art-wallpaper-hd.jpg' class='img_round' height='500px' width='500px'></center>";
    }



   ?>
```

Comment: What is the issue your are facing?

Comment: please print_r($data_array) and then see at which index the image value is comming. can you paste here the print_r result

Comment: Hi, where abouts should I put it? If i put it up top I get 'Null', if I put it under '$data_array = $q->fetch();' I get bool(false)

Comment: yes you have to put it under   $data_array = $q->fetch();. Can you run your query directly in phpmyadmin. like echo te query and run it directly in phpmy admin. echo "SELECT * FROM pages_extra WHERE name=$_POST['page_header']"

Comment: so we make sure that query is getting some data from database